# JS in HTML Game Won't Run

Tags: javascript, html, nested

I'm trying to build a Rock/Paper/Scissor game, first-to-five, in a script tag in HTML. As far as I can tell everything is A-ok, but when I run it I receive an error message in the console at my closing script tag.

Can you folks take a look and let me know:

1.) Why I'm getting an error message at the closing script tag, and what I need to do to resolve that and have that code run as I want it to?

2.) If you have any suggestions for my code in general? I'm self taught and trying to soak up as much as possible.

```js
//Game parameters to start 
var computerScore = 0
var playerScore = 0

//Game functions
function game() {
  while (computerScore >= 5 && playerScore >= 5) {

    //Computer Selection 
    function computerPlay() {

      let playerSelection = prompt("Make your choice: rock, paper, or scissors!")
      let computerSelection = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)

      //Player Selection
      if (playerSelection.toLowerCase() == "rock") {
        var playerChoice = 0;
      } else if (playerSelection.toLowerCase() == "paper") {
        var playerChoice = 1;
      } else if (playerSelection.toLowerCase() == "scissors") {
        var playerChoice = 2;
      } else {
        alert("Sorry, that word isn't recognized. Please select rock, paper, or scissors.")
      }

      //Rock
      if (computerSelection == 0) {
        var computerChoice = 0
        //Paper
      } else if (computerSelection == 1) {
        var computerChoice = 1
        //Scissors
      } else if (computerSelection == 2) {
        var computerChoice = 2
      } else {}

      //OUTCOMES 
      if (computerSelection == 0 && playerChoice == 0 || computerSelection == 1 && playerChoice == 1 || computerSelection == 2 && playerChoice == 2) {
        alert("Tie game!")
      } else if (computerSelection == 1 && playerChoice == 0) {
        alert("Paper beats rock. You lose!")
      } else if (computerSelection == 2 && playerChoice == 0) {
        alert("Rock beats scissors. You win!")
      } else if (computerSelection == 0 && playerChoice == 1) {
        alert("Paper beats rock. You win!")
      } else if (computerSelection == 0 && playerChoice == 2) {
        alert("Rock beats scissors. You lose!")
      } else if (computerSelection == 1 && playerChoice == 2) {
        alert("Scissors beat paper. You win!")
      } else if (computerSelection == 2 && playerChoice == 1) {
        alert("Scissors beat paper. You lose!")
      } else {}

      //Increments 
      if (computerSelection > playerChoice) {

        computerScore++
      } else if (computerSelection < playerChoice) {
        playerScore++
      } else {}

      if (computerScore == 5 && playerScore < 5) {
        alert("Computer wins, " + computerScore + " to " + playerScore + "!")
      } else if (playerScore == 5 && computerScore < 5) {
        alert("Player wins, " + playerScore + " to " + computerScore + "!")
      } else {}


    }

    game()
```

Comment: Looks like the [perfect oportunity to debug your application by yourself](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Yeah, specifically this: `if (computerSelection == 0 && playerChoice == 0 || computerSelection == 1 && playerChoice == 1 || computerSelection == 2 && playerChoice == 2) {`

Comment: You need two more closing brackets `}` before calling `game()`

Comment: Also `computerScore >= 5 && playerScore >= 5` is never true when you start

Comment: so I made you a snippet and formatted it. It will help you see where the missing brackets go. HINT, you likely want something like `function game() {
  while (computerScore <= 5 && playerScore <= 5) {
computerPlay();
}}

    function computerPlay() { ... `  Notice the `}}` before the second function

Comment: Using a decent IDE to write your code will help you avoid bracket problems like this.

Comment: Okay, there are some really helpful tips here! I will give your snippet a shot. Thank you!

Comment: @Barmar do you have any recommendations for IDEs? I've been using TextWrangler.

Comment: TextWrangler is more of a text editor than an IDE, although I'd expect it to do things like showing matching braces. I use PhpStorm, it's pretty good, but I don't have experience with other IDEs.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the tip! I will look into PhpStorm as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there's a couple things here,

Firstly your game function has no closing bracket.

Secondly your computerPlay function inside your game function is never called (and it also has no closing bracket but I would suggest removing it anyway)

Thirdly your while condition (line 12) triggers when computer/playerScore is more than 5 but on lines 7 and 8 you set them to 0. You probably want them as less than or equal to instead.

See fixed version below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML >
<html>

<body>
  <script>
    //Game parameters to start 
    var computerScore = 0
    var playerScore = 0

    //Game functions
    function game() {
      while (computerScore <= 5 && playerScore <= 5) {

        //Computer Selection 
        let playerSelection = prompt("Make your choice: rock, paper, or scissors!")
        let computerSelection = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)

        //Player Selection
        if (playerSelection.toLowerCase() == "rock") {
          var playerChoice = 0;
        } else if (playerSelection.toLowerCase() == "paper") {
          var playerChoice = 1;
        } else if (playerSelection.toLowerCase() == "scissors") {
          var playerChoice = 2;
        } else {
          alert("Sorry, that word isn't recognized. Please select rock, paper, or scissors.")
        }

        //Rock
        if (computerSelection == 0) {
          var computerChoice = 0
          //Paper
        } else if (computerSelection == 1) {
          var computerChoice = 1
          //Scissors
        } else if (computerSelection == 2) {
          var computerChoice = 2
        } else {}

        //OUTCOMES 
        if (computerSelection == 0 && playerChoice == 0 || computerSelection == 1 && playerChoice == 1 || computerSelection == 2 && playerChoice == 2) {
          alert("Tie game!")
        } else if (computerSelection == 1 && playerChoice == 0) {
          alert("Paper beats rock. You lose!")
        } else if (computerSelection == 2 && playerChoice == 0) {
          alert("Rock beats scissors. You win!")
        } else if (computerSelection == 0 && playerChoice == 1) {
          alert("Paper beats rock. You win!")
        } else if (computerSelection == 0 && playerChoice == 2) {
          alert("Rock beats scissors. You lose!")
        } else if (computerSelection == 1 && playerChoice == 2) {
          alert("Scissors beat paper. You win!")
        } else if (computerSelection == 2 && playerChoice == 1) {
          alert("Scissors beat paper. You lose!")
        } else {}

        //Increments 
        if (computerSelection > playerChoice) {

          computerScore++
        } else if (computerSelection < playerChoice) {
          playerScore++
        } else {}

        if (computerScore == 5 && playerScore < 5) {
          alert("Computer wins, " + computerScore + " to " + playerScore + "!")
        } else if (playerScore == 5 && computerScore < 5) {
          alert("Player wins, " + playerScore + " to " + computerScore + "!")
        } else {}

      }
    }

    game();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. I'm going to review what you provided here against what I provided earlier.

Comment: No worries, useful tip: if you indent your code neatly, you can easily make sure each function has a matching closing bracket!

Comment: Basically all answered in comments to the question  - a question with accepted answers cannot be deleted by the asker, as should have been the case here. There  is nothing about the question nor the answer that is useful for other visitors than OP

Comment: @mplungjan okay, sorry about that. still learning the ins-and-outs. will be more mindful going forward.